# Django Rest Framework set the pagination_class on an individual API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I set `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` in **settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
}
```

And I have an api need to return all data in database without paginator
I set `pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination`

**views.py**

```
class LayerList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Layer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LayerSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    filter_class = LayerFilter
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

But this api stiil have pagination function  :

```
{
    "count": 18,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

What else should I setting???

**UDDATE**

`LimitOffsetPagination` is still a Pagination explained by @AkramParvez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want ro return all data withou paginator you should set `pagination_class=None`. Then you don't use pagination at all. 
Is it that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you are right. None is what I want. I misunderstanding the ````LimitOffsetPagination```` ,I should edit my question to avoid other people confused. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Both the apis return the same pagination json which contain `count`, `next`, `previous` and `results` keys. The difference is in the request query parameters.
`PageNumberPagination` uses `https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=4`
and returns

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

While
`LimitOffsetPagination` uses `https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=400`
and returns

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=500",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=300",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to make sure one thing: LimitOffsetPagination will return all data without max_limitation,right???

Comment: I had ever seen a format is like :````{"layer1":"value1","layer2","value2"}```` without ````count````,````next````,previous````,````result````, what's the format called ??